# How do you add a shadow to a progress bar (horizontal)?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-progressbar

I am using API 22 and want to add shadows to my progress bar and toolbar, but my first focus is on the progress bar. Is it possible to do this? If so, how?

I tried using the shadow attributes, but those didn't seem to work.

Here is an example of what I want the progress bar to look like:

Link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/m1rd7.png

It has a nice slight shadow above and below it.
Currently I'm using a CardView with a child ProgressBar.

Comment: Check it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40396026/progress-bar-shadow-only-on-filled-part

Comment: I tried that. It didn't work as intended and the second <item> in the root <layer-list> didn't actually do anything. Thanks though.

Comment: did u manage to figure this out?